# Variable not setting itself correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm learning jQuery and I have got following problem. In my code I have got variable `prev_content` and I want display content of that variable in new `.dialog()`. Variable is defined globally, then content is set in `.click()` function, but variable returning `UNDEFINED`

```
$('body').append('<div class="ui-dialog" id="jp_main_menu"><ul id="jp_templates_list"></ul></div>');                                    console.debug(jp_console_title + "[OK] #jp_main_menu - creating element");
JPTemplateGetList();
var prev_content;
$(".jp_show_preview_window").click(function(){
    prev_content = jp_tpl[$(this).attr("id")].source;
    $('#jp_preview_window').dialog("open");
    return false;
});
$('#jp_main_menu').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: false,
    resizable: true,
    draggable: true,
    position: ['center',100],
    title: "MY WINDOW",
    width: 600
});                                                                                                                                     console.debug(jp_console_title + "[OK] #jp_main_menu - setting jQuery .dialog function");
$('body').append('<div class="ui-dialog" id="jp_preview_window">'+ prev_content +'</div>');
```

As you can see, variable content is set on line:

```
prev_content = jp_tpl[$(this).attr("id")].source;
```

But when I wanna display that content (last line of my code), it will show `UNDEFINED`.

Can you help me please? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a matter of timing.  Your last line of code runs BEFORE you trigger the click handler, thus your variable is still `undefined` as the code to set it has not been called yet (it isn't called until the mouse click happens).

Move the last line to be inside the click handler:

```
$('body').append('<div class="ui-dialog" id="jp_main_menu"><ul id="jp_templates_list"></ul></div>');                                    console.debug(jp_console_title + "[OK] #jp_main_menu - creating element");
JPTemplateGetList();
$(".jp_show_preview_window").click(function(){
    var prev_content = jp_tpl[$(this).attr("id")].source;
    $('body').append('<div class="ui-dialog" id="jp_preview_window">'+ prev_content +'</div>'); 
    $('#jp_preview_window').dialog("open");
    return false;
});
$('#jp_main_menu').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: false,
    resizable: true,
    draggable: true,
    position: ['center',100],
    title: "MY WINDOW",
    width: 600
});
```

Comment: thanks, that`s what I need :) I will mark this as answer ASAP. Thanks :)